# Robot framework Return value from keyword in for loop is't passed through

Tags: robotframework

For a test I made 2 keywords. The general idea is to check in a range of objects if a certain field, fieldname and message is present. If the field or fieldname is absent the keyword has to return to forloop. The keyword has to return `${index}` and `${result}`. When I run this test and it fails the variable ${results} is shown as `${result}=None` and when the test passes it becomes `${result}= [3, u'PASS']`

I think this has something to do with the `${result}=` in the forloop

I tried `Run keyword and return` but it didn't work, i am a little confused where to put the `${variables}` and where to use it.
Can anyone help me to figure this out?

FORLOOP:

```
${index}= |  set variable |   0
${result}= | Set Variable |  not started
: FOR   | ${value} |   IN RANGE |  ${index}  | 15
        \    ${resultaat}= |"other keyword" | ${index} 
        \    ${index}= |   "keyword add 1 to index" |   ${index}
        \    Return From Keyword if  |  '${result}'=='PASS'
${testsuccess}= |  Set Variable If | '${result}'=='PASS' | TEST GESLAAGD
```

the 'other keyword' is:

```
[ARGS] ${index} 
${index}= | set variable | ${index}
${check1}= <IS FIELD THERE>
${result}= | set variable if | ${check1}==False | FIELD NOT THERE
return from keyword if | ${check1}=False
${check2}= <HAS FIELD VALUE X>
${result}= | set variable if | ${check2}==False | WRONG VALUE
return from keyword if | ${check2}=False
${check3}= <IS MESSAGE X>
${result}= | set variable if | ${check3}==False | FAIL
${result}= | set variable if | ${check3}==True | PASS
[RETURN] ${index} ${result}
```

LOG:
keyword = `'${result}'=='PASS'`
FOR = `'${testsucces}=None'` (But that is not right because the condition has been met)

Answer (score 1):

`Set Variable If` sets the value to `None` once there isn't any 'Else' option and the condition isn't met. See doc: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If

So adapt your code:

```
${result} | Set Variable If | ${check3}==False | FAIL
... | ${check3}==True | PASS
```

as shown in documentation examples.

Comment: Thx, for your anwser, but I am creating this test and i using the good path. So the Result is always met and therefor not the solution to my problem. I will add this to my quetion. But when i run the test, the variable '${result}'=='PASS' is set in the keyword, but in the FORLOOP it is None, so the value from the keyword is'nt passed on to the FORLOOP

Answer (score 0):

It works when i put `${result}` after the `return from keyword if`

for example:

```
return from keyword if | ${check1}=False | ${result}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for return inside the for loop

```
*** Keywords ***
ReturnFromForLoop
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    5
       Return From Keyword    ${i}
    END
ReturnFromForLoopWithIf
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    5
       Return From Keyword If    ${i}==2    ${i}
    END
```